# Get details of employee whose salary came after his release date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables - `Employee` and `Salary`.

Employee has 3 columns : 
`EmpId , JoiningDate and LastDate.`

Salary table has 3 columns : 
`EmpId, SalaryPerMonth, SalaryDate.`

```
select * from salG;

1   02-FEB-2016 100
2   31-JAN-2016 200
2   28-FEB-2016 200
2   01-APR-2016 200
3   30-JAN-2016 300
3   23-FEB-2016 300
3   29-MAR-2016 300

select * from empG;

1   01-JAN-2016 31-JAN-2016
2   10-JAN-2016 31-MAR-2016
3   11-JAN-2016 31-MAR-2016
```

I need to get empId and SalaryPerMonth of those employees whose salary came after their lastDate.

I tried -

```
select emp.id,s.salary 
from empG emp,
salG s
where emp.END_DATE < ( select max(s.sal_date) from salG s where emp.id= s.id);
```

But this is a cartesian product. Is there a better way?

Comment: @sstan : It;s like you are a mind reader. I was just googling on how to format. Please provide me the link. Highly appreciated.

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you Sir. And no, I don't do this on purpose. You won't get a chance to say this from my next question :)

Comment: btw, it's very good that you added the sample data of your tables.  But don't forget to include what your expected result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided sample expected output but from what I understand this should meet your needs just fine. No need for subqueries or any of that, you can do the logic in the join;

Sample table 'Employee'

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Employee
CREATE TABLE #Employee (EmpID int, JoiningDate date, LastDate date)
INSERT INTO #Employee
VALUES
(1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-31')
,(2, '2016-01-10','2016-03-31')
,(3, '2016-01-11','2016-03-31')
```

Sample Table 'Salary'

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Salary') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Salary
CREATE TABLE #Salary (EmpId int, SalaryPerMonth int, SalaryDate date)
INSERT INTO #Salary
VALUES
 (1, 100, '2016-02-02')
,(2, 200, '2016-01-31')
,(2, 200, '2016-02-28')
,(2, 200, '2016-04-01')
,(3, 300, '2016-01-30')
,(3, 300, '2016-02-23')
,(3, 300, '2016-03-29')
```

Query

```
SELECT
    e.EmpID
    ,e.JoiningDate
    ,e.LastDate
    ,s.SalaryDate
    ,s.SalaryPerMonth
FROM #Employee e
INNER JOIN #Salary s
    ON e.EmpID = s.EmpId
    AND e.LastDate < s.SalaryDate
```

Output

```
EmpID   JoiningDate LastDate    SalaryDate  SalaryPerMonth
1       2016-01-01  2016-01-31  2016-02-02  100
2       2016-01-10  2016-03-31  2016-04-01  200
```

Comment: What language is that? It doesn't look like Oracle SQL; in Oracle SQL, table names may not include #.

Comment: yeah, that's sql server but those table names are just temporary tables so that i don't have to make actual tables in my test systems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two tables at all in the outer query:

```
select s.id, s.salary 
from salG s
where s.sal_date > (select e.END_DATE from empg e where e.id = s.id);
```

This seems like a more direct translation of what you are asking for.